# Regex for cisco acl

Tags: asr

Did anyone come across any regex that can be used in cisco acl to fetch what is the last permit statement in an ACL? I have almost 5k ACL permit lines and few deny statements in the end, so everytime i have to add a permit line i have to scroll all the lines and find out the right sequence number to add a permit line just above the deny statements. I tried to get the access-list by using the tail command with the count but since the list keeps varying, just wanted to check if there is any regex i can use to display when the access-list statements changes from permit to deny?

Comment: It sounds like you have a badly constructed ACL. There is an implicit deny at the end, so placing the deny statements at the end is pointless. You probably want to deny first, then permit everything else.

Comment: Also, you may have exceeded the TCAM limit on the device. It sounds like it's time to reevaluate the ACL and what it is doing.

Comment: Hey, ofcourse we are planning to remove the ACL's from the device itself in the near future, the acl's are to permit specific IP's only ingress. Any feedback on the regex that can be used?

Comment: Regex? No. Script? Yes. (esp one not running on the router itself.) It's best to avoid such complex ACLs. Or, as I do, maintain them externally where it's trivial to edit.

Comment: Two complications: (1) stored config doesn't keep sequence numbers, (2) *show* doesn't include remarks. My "internet inbound" acl is ~460 lines. It's externally generated, and as long as the router hasn't reloaded, I know the seq# to manually insert a new rule. (I can share the script if you'd like)

Comment: Hi @RickyBeam sorry for the late answer, yes, we dont have any remarks either, please do let me know if you can share the script, i will try and check if fits my need. Thanks very much

Comment: I'd simply download the config and use an editor...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the rep points to comment above but, what Ron Maupin said about the explicit deny being pointless is wrong.  With only the implicit deny, you will only see denied traffic if your logging level is set to Debugging or you're using "terminal monitor".  If your logging level is anything lower than Debugging (such as Error) you will not see the denied traffic unless you have an explicit deny statement (along with logging enabled on it).

Also, as for his statement about having the denies first, that's fine in certain situations but, take this example as a counter-point:

```
ip access-list extended example-acl
 10 permit udp host 192.168.34.14 8.8.8.8 53
 20 deny ip 192.168.34.0 0.0.0.255 any
 30 permit ip any any
```

I've allowed a single host to access DNS on 8.8.8.8 but then blocked everything else on that network from going anywhere, while then allowing all other networks flowing through whatever interface the ACL is applied to, to access what they need.  If I had the deny statement listed first, my host permit statement would not work.  Without knowing your specific needs, you can't just say denies should always be first.

Also, you don't have to scroll to find the next sequence number, assuming you know the sequence stepping amount (by 10s, by 20s, etc.).  All you have to do is

```
show access-list <acl name> | begin deny
```

Once you see the sequence number that the deny statement is on, just subtract a number from it or whatever you need, and you would be able to insert a new statement above it.  Then, just resequence your ACL at the end by using

```
resequence ip access-list <acl name> <starting number> <stepping number>
```

Comment: Could you be explicit about which debug you’re referring to when you say that you can see implicit denies.  This probably isn’t obvious to all readers

Comment: My bad.  logging buffered debug